# 403 forbidden access to non-Wordpress subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website on a Centos server with wp super cache plugin, and have created a sub folder in the root directory with chmod 777.
But i have a error 403 forbidden return when i try to access a file in this directory.

the htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WPSuperCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>

# END WPSuperCache

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried to add this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myfolder/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it's not working.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check error log for this - it should have enough information on the problem, anyways here is what I think should help:

```
<Directory /path/to/wordpress/root>
Require all granted #for apache 2.4 or Allow from all for 2.2
AllowOverride All
Options +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, after adding your sample, i have this error in logs:
"<Directory not allowed here" where should i copy this code?

Comment: In your VirtualHost directive preferably or in apache2.conf, please check "context" in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory